# Is console is object?

Tags: javascript, console

I have a query regarding JavaScript.

In the context of JavaScript programming, I understand that 'console' is often utilized for debugging and displaying information.

Is the 'console' considered an object in JavaScript?

Furthermore, as 'log' is a method frequently used within 'console' for outputting messages, does 'log' have to be contained within the 'console' object?

I'm seeking clarification to better understand the structure and usage of these elements within the JavaScript environment

Comment: You can also hit `F12` and type just `console` and enter, then you can explore the properties, protoype etc

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console

Comment: The console is an API, of which there are many in Javascript. the "console" itself is indeed an object. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console_API

Comment: You can note that it is a special object, as `console.toString()` gives `[object console]` instead of `[object Object]` for a regular object

Answer (score 1):

console is an object.

```js
//type of console
console.log(typeof console) 
//output: object


//properties inside the console object
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(console))
//output: ["debug", "error", "log", "info", "w...]
```

Answer (score 0):

`console` is indeed an object. Proof:

```js
document.write(typeof console);
```

Whenever you are unsure what the type of a certain entity is, you can use `typeof` in order to find that out.

I would expect `log` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log_static) to be defined, because it's specified in the standard, see https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#console-namespace

Comment: I wonder why was this answer down-voted. What needs to be improved in it.

Comment: Yes there seems to be more and more lunatics on the site, this is why I'm about to stop contributing.. gave you my vote to even the score, I find this answer more useful than the other

Comment: @NurgulKereikhan happy to help. If the answers solved your problem, then you might consider accepting the best answer as the correct one.